# I am trying to call AWS lex intent B from Intent B in lambda function using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I used below code to but it did not work for me

```
def confirm_intent(session_attributes, intent_name, slots, message):
    return {
        'sessionAttributes': session_attributes,
        'dialogAction': {
            'type': 'ConfirmIntent',
            'intentName': intent_name,
            'slots': slots,
            'message': {
                'contentType': 'PlainText',
                'content': message
            }
        }
    }
msg = "Hi, I am a xxx-BOT. i can help you with following: A B C"

return confirm_intent(output_session_attributes, 'intent-B', new_slot, msg)
```

after using below code i was not able to traverse to different intent.

Comment: Do you mean that you're trying to move from Intent A to Intent B? Specifically, you want to move to the confirmation prompt of Intent B once all the slots for Intent A are filled? Could you please clarify your question a bit more?

Comment: once values entered in intent A based on the value entered i need to move to  intent B and then i need to enter value of slot B in intent B to fulfil the bot.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this desired behaviour using a custom Lambda function.

The below is a snippet of the JSON input format into your function. Ensure that the `name` of the `currentIntent` matches IntentA's name. Then, take a look at `confirmationStatus` and specifically look for a value of `Confirmed` which tells you that all mandatory slots have been filled and the user has confirmed their intention.

```
"currentIntent": {
    "name": "intent-name",
    "nluIntentConfidenceScore": score,
    "slots": {
      "slot name": "value",
      "slot name": "value"
    },
    "slotDetails": {
      "slot name": {
        "resolutions" : [
          { "value": "resolved value" },
          { "value": "resolved value" }
        ],
        "originalValue": "original text"
      },
      "slot name": {
        "resolutions" : [
          { "value": "resolved value" },
          { "value": "resolved value" }
        ],
        "originalValue": "original text"
      }
    },
    "confirmationStatus": "None, Confirmed, or Denied (intent confirmation, if configured)"
  },
```

You can then return a response which will instruct Lex to ask the user to enter a value for the corresponding slot in IntentB.

The below is an extract from the Lex-Lambda developer guide:

> ElicitSlot — Informs Amazon Lex that the user is expected to provide a slot value in the response.

> The intentName, slotToElicit, and slots fields are required. The
> message and responseCard fields are optional. If you don't specify a
> message, Amazon Lex uses one of the slot elicitation prompts
> configured for the slot.

The below snippet provides an example of what values need to be present in the response from Lambda.

```
 "dialogAction": {
    "type": "ElicitSlot",
    "message": {
      "contentType": "PlainText or SSML or CustomPayload",
      "content": "Message to convey to the user. For example, What size pizza would you like?"
    },
   "intentName": "intent-name",
   "slots": {
      "slot-name": "value",
      "slot-name": "value",
      "slot-name": "value"  
   },
   "slotToElicit" : "slot-name"
```

You can find the request and response formats here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/lambda-input-response-format.html

Comment: I do not want user to enter value for intent B, it should be within lambda, its internal validation for the user input.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you're asking is allowed within Lex. You could try using `ConfirmIntent` as your `dialogAction` type. Which would get you close. Unfortunately when using `dialogAction` type of `Close`, the schema does not appear to look at the intent name. You could try it though and see if it works for you. I would suggest you revisit your design to find a better way to achieve your goal.